# How to get the calling node inside the controller of JavaFX program

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm doing a javafx program, and I'm stuck when I trying to let many node share the same onAction function.

Here's 37 of label node inside the program and I added them into an ArrayList, and all of them shares the same function `blockChange`

```xml
<Label fx:id="b66" onMouseClicked="#blockChange" text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
    <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
    </font>
</Label>
```

I tried to implement the function that change the text of the label every time I clicked the label. But I cannot specify which is the label that call the function. I'm wondering if there's any way to get the calling node inside the Controller?

```java
@FXML
void blockChange(MouseEvent event){
    //I want to get the calling label here
}
```

Comment: Class `MouseEvent` inherits method [getSource()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html?is-external=true#getSource--)

Comment: I always prefer to give each node its own listener. Since you've already put these in a list, you can iterate through the list and register a listener with each node (in the controller's `initialize()` method). That way the label firing the event is simply the label with which the listener was registered; this avoids calling `getSource()` and downcasting the result.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for those information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the source like this:

```java
@FXML
void blockChange(MouseEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source instanceof Label) {
        ((Label) source).setText("new Text");
    }
}
```

But as mentioned in the comments, if you already have all the labels in one collection, you can iterate over the collection and add `EventHandler` for each of them:

```java
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    //...
    labels.forEach(this::addMouseClickedEventHandler);
}

private void addMouseClickedEventHandler(Label label) {
    label.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        label.setText("new text");
        event.consume();
    });
}
```